# Why do I have both 0.13 and 1.0 in my sbt folder?

Tags: scala, sbt

I installed sbt and now I am looking at `.sbt` in order to install global plugins

```
~/.sbt$ ll
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  5 miki miki 4096 јун 30 20:48 ./
drwxr-xr-x 87 miki miki 4096 јун 30 20:48 ../
drwxr-xr-x  3 miki miki 4096 јун 30 20:46 0.13/
drwxr-xr-x  3 miki miki 4096 јун 30 20:48 1.0/
drwxr-xr-x  3 miki miki 4096 јун 30 20:48 boot/
```

Anyway,sbt reference manual says

```
This version of sbt (sbt 0.13) is outdated and not supported!
```

What should I do? Is my config the proper one?

Comment: Remove the 0.13 directory?

Comment: This is normal. Every project gets to choose their own sbt version. If you have a project that wants 0.13.x, you need that directory. What you should do is update all projects (where you can) to use sbt 1.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different projects can use different versions of sbt. Normally it is set in `project/build.properties`. So if you clone some project that uses sbt 0.13, and launch sbt in it, it will be sbt 0.13, even if your sbt launcher is version 1.x.

sbt stores settings and other stuff in `~/.sbt/0.13`, so you shouldn't remove it. You can have different sets of global settings and plugins for sbt 0.13 and sbt 1. Not all plugins exist for both versions of sbt, so it can't be unified.